# Replacing new line (\n) in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Trying to replace two or more new lines for one. Doc has images.

First i try to do line this:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
body.replaceText("\\n{2,}", '\n');
```

But Apps Script method replaceText does not accept escape characters.

Then I tried this:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var bodyText = body.getText();
bodyText = bodyText.replace(/\n{2,}/, "\n");
body.setText(bodyText);
```

It works, but all images was miss.

How can i replace newlines with save Doc images?

Comment: What do you mean that all images was miss? Could you maybe provide a sample doc to test this and understand what you mean by that. Remember that this methods use [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) as a regEx engine in case you need to look for specific features.

Comment: Missing because getText() method return only text content, without images and other. And when i called setText() all in Doc was rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

In Google docs, paragraphs are separated by `\n`(newlines). A paragraph cannot contain a new line. Any new line character inside a paragraph is converted to `\r`. The `replaceText` documentation states:

> The provided regular expression pattern is **independently matched against each text block** contained in the current element.

So, `\n` cannot be used, because a text block(part of paragraph) cannot contain `\n`.

#### Solution:

One way to consider subsequent new lines is to consider them as empty paragraphs:

- paragraphs with no children and
- whose text is empty

On that note, We can remove those empty paragraphs:

#### Snippet:

```
function removeEmptyParagraphs() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
    .getBody()
    .getParagraphs()
    .forEach(para => {
      const numChild = para.getNumChildren();
      const txt = para.getText();
      if (numChild === 0 && txt === '') para.removeFromParent();
    });
}
```

#### References:

- [Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph)
- [Body#replaceText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String))

Comment: Sample of code remove all paragraph where text is empty, not only where >=2, but solution is great, thanks!